# Pass value of checkbox to variable only if it checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am using iCheck for checkbox and below checkbox selection html,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="allDay" id="allDay" class="icheck" data-checkbox="icheckbox_minimal-red" value="true"> All day event</label>
```

I am submitting form using Ajax, but not with `.serialize()` function, i am taking individual form entry as `.val()` and then do some manipulation on entry and then pass as variable in form ajax data,

Now i want to pass value for checkbox if its selected, otherwise it should not pass any value,

I have below code for taking value for variable,

```
allDay = $('#allDay').val();
```

But with this, it always pass ***value = true*** even if its `checked` or `unchecked`.

How can i pass value of checkbox to variable only if it checked?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `:checked` selector:

```
allDay = $('#allDay:checked').val();
```

or instead you can use `.is()` too if you are looking for default value:

```
allDay = $('#allDay').is(':checked'); // "true" if checked | "false" on unchecked;
```